# How do I pass properties with maven pom file into placeholder values of properties file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, kubernetes, environment-variables

I have an application that I'm trying to pass configuration properties to through Kubernetes configmaps once deployed to a cluster. I'm unable to build the application (with maven) however because the properties I'm referencing in the application do not exist at compile time. Also, I'm trying to reference these variables with the Spring @Value annotation.

I've attempted to use placeholders in the properties file and pass in properties with maven profiles and properties.

application.yaml

```
DATABASE_URL: ${placeholderOne}
```

pom.xml

```
<profile>
    <id>local</id>
    <properties>
        <placeholderOne>url</placeholderOne>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Controller.java

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Value("${DATABASE_URL}")
    private String dbUrl;

    @GetMapping("/endpointOne")
    public Greeting greeting() {

        return new Greeting(1, dbUrl);
    }

}
```

With this attempted solution I keep getting the error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'placeholderOne' in value "${placeholderOne}"` I've tried cleaning and building with the command `mvn clean install -Plocal`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or proposals of other solutions to what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: My assumption is that this is a spring / spring boot project where you shouldn't use maven profiles... better use either `application.properties` and `application-dev.properties` or multi document yaml files see for details into the spring boot docs...

Comment: Please refer to [Using System Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.4/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run.examples.system-properties)

Comment: You should use a mix of application.properties and ENV variables and at application level, inject values with validation if not present on properties, took the one defined as ENV variable